# Python Negative Binomial Regression - Results Don't Match those from R

Tags: python, r, statistics, statsmodels

I'm experimenting with negative binomial regression using Python. I found this example using R, along with a data set:

http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~pesta/NMFM404/NB.html

I tried to replicate the results on the web page using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf 
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.read_stata("http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~pesta/prednasky/NMFM404/Data/nb_data.dta")

model = smf.glm(formula = "daysabs ~ math + prog", data=df, family=sm.families.NegativeBinomial()).fit()

model.summary()
```

Unfortunately this didn't give the same coefficients. It gave the following:

```
coef        std err     z       P>|z|   [95.0% Conf. Int.]
Intercept    3.4875     0.236   14.808  0.000    3.026  3.949
math        -0.0067     0.003   -2.600  0.009   -0.012 -0.002
prog        -0.6781     0.101   -6.683  0.000   -0.877 -0.479
```

These aren't even close to those on the website. Assuming the R code is correct, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for the discrepancy is that when you are reading in the dataset with Pandas, the `prog` variable is treated as type `float` by default:

```
df.prog.head()

0    2.0
1    2.0
2    2.0
3    2.0
4    2.0
Name: prog, dtype: float32
```

In the R example, on the other hand, the `prog` variable was explicitly cast to a factor (categorical) variable:

```
dat <- within(dat, {
    prog <- factor(prog, levels = 1:3, labels = c("General", "Academic", "Vocational"))
    id <- factor(id)
})
```

As a result, when you look at the fit summary in R, you can see that the `prog` variable has been split into n-1 binary-encoded terms:

```
> summary(m1 <- glm.nb(daysabs ~ math + prog, data = dat))

Call:
glm.nb(formula = daysabs ~ math + prog, data = dat, init.theta = 1.032713156, 
    link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.1547  -1.0192  -0.3694   0.2285   2.5273  

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     2.615265   0.197460  13.245  < 2e-16 ***
math           -0.005993   0.002505  -2.392   0.0167 *  
progAcademic   -0.440760   0.182610  -2.414   0.0158 *  
progVocational -1.278651   0.200720  -6.370 1.89e-10 ***
```

Compare this to how the `prog` variable appears in the Python fit summary you posted.

To fix the issue, you can use the [`C()` function](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/example_formulas.html#categorical-variables) to cast the variable to categorical in statsmodels. This way you will arrive at the same result:

```
model = smf.glm(formula = "daysabs ~ math + C(prog)", data=df, family=sm.families.NegativeBinomial()).fit()
model.summary()

<class 'statsmodels.iolib.summary.Summary'>
"""
                 Generalized Linear Model Regression Results                  
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                daysabs   No. Observations:                  314
Model:                            GLM   Df Residuals:                      310
Model Family:        NegativeBinomial   Df Model:                            3
Link Function:                    log   Scale:                   1.06830885199
Method:                          IRLS   Log-Likelihood:                -865.68
Date:                Thu, 16 Feb 2017   Deviance:                       350.98
Time:                        10:34:16   Pearson chi2:                     331.
No. Iterations:                     6                                         
==================================================================================
                     coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept          2.6150      0.207     12.630      0.000       2.209       3.021
C(prog)[T.2.0]    -0.4408      0.192     -2.302      0.021      -0.816      -0.065
C(prog)[T.3.0]    -1.2786      0.210     -6.079      0.000      -1.691      -0.866
math              -0.0060      0.003     -2.281      0.023      -0.011      -0.001
==================================================================================
"""
```

Comment: Aha!! V Cool - Thanks!

Comment: The results are now close, but still not exactly the same e.g. the intercept coefficient is 2.6150 vs. in R it is 2.61526. I assume this is nothing to be worried about but what would be the reason for the slight difference?

Comment: Note, that statsmodels GLM does not fix the scale equal to 1 for negative binomial. So, standard errors might differ to R because statsmodels defaults to Quasi-NegativeBinomial in GLM. I don't know if this is a bug or a feature of statsmodels https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2888 .

Comment: If you run a negative binomial regression in R with a fixed theta (i.e. alpha in statsmodel) parameter, you get the same standard errors: `round(summary(m1 <- glm(daysabs ~ math + as.factor(prog), family=negative.binomial(theta=1.033), data = dat))$coefficients[,2],3)` = `0.207            0.003            0.191            0.210 `