# Modified negative binomial GLM in Python

Tags: python, glm, statsmodels, pymc3

Packages `pymc3` and `statsmodels` can handle negative binomial GLMs in Python as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277532/python-negative-binomial-regression-results-dont-match-those-from-r):

E(Y) = e^(beta_0 + Sigma (X_i * beta_i))

Where `X_i`s are my predictor variables and `Y` is my dependent variable. Is there a way to force one my variables (for example `X_1`) to have `beta_1=1` so that the algorithm optimizes other coefficients. I am open to using both `pymc3` and `statsmodels`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GLM and the count models in statsmodels.discrete include and optional keyword `offset` which is exactly for this use case. It is added to the linear prediction part, and so corresponds to an additional variable with fixed coefficient equal to 1.

http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.html
http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.NegativeBinomial.html

Aside: GLM with family NegativeBinomial takes the negative binomial dispersion parameter as fixed, while the discrete model NegativeBinomial estimates the dispersion parameter by MLE jointly with the mean parameters.

Another aside: GLM has a `fit_constrained` method for linear or affine restrictions on the parameters. This works by transforming the design matrix and using `offset` for the constant part. In the simple case of a fixed parameter as in the question, this reduces to using offset in the same way as described above (although fit_constrained has to go through the more costly general case.)