# python glm numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, glm

I'm trying to do a glm with the negative binomial on my current dataset. I know it can be done via statmodels as shown here: [Python Negative Binomial Regression - Results Don't Match those from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277532/python-negative-binomial-regression-results-dont-match-those-from-r) . However the problem is that my data is in the form of a 2-dimensional numpy array, while the code there assumes the data is in the pandas format.

I could convert the data to that format, but my data is over 10,000 rows long, and I need to do the glm on each row, only grabbing the p-values (so I end up with an array of >10,000 p-values), so I'm not sure how messy the code would be, or how efficient it would be time wise.

Is it possible to run the glm (from statmodels or elsewhere) of a negative binomial on numpy arrays? And if so how?